# Bitcoin Core data to csv

Tags: transactions

I would like to download the Bitcoin blockchain and use the data for machine learning purposes. For this, I have to get the data into a workable format like csv or a flat JSON etc.

I've read about approaches and the most common one seems to be through a monkeyDB. Do you know a source code that implements this method? Or do you know other methods that could be used to get the Ethereum blockchain data into a modeling friendly format?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about the ethereum blockchain or bitcoin ?

Comment: I am talking about Bitcoin blockchain. The reason I mention Ethereum is, that if the Ethereum blockchain is easier to parse and aggregate data from, I could use this data instead of Bitcoin data.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing, however, there's no explicit source of blockchain data on the internet. You'll have to download the entire blockchain transaction history by downloading Bitcoin Core to have the data at the first place. Then you'll need some parser to convert the data in raw format to more readable formats like csv or JSON.

Comment: I have downloaded Bitcoin Core and have all data available. I have some flat csv's, but need to get these aggregated and extract features from the data. The flat csv's I have is: Transactions, Blocks, tx_in, and tx_out.
Do you have any experience on how to aggregate this data into e.g. users with a certain balance.

Comment: I've seen different parsers, but haven't got to the level of any meaningful analysis. But I would assume it would be hard once the data is parsed, since it's already in a nice input/output format.

Answer (score 0):

We just released the full bitcoin blockchain data in JSON format, together with methods and tools to collect and process them.

See your paper:
[Full Bitcoin Blockchain Data Made Easy](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08072)

Comments welcome!